# Spacy to redact/sanitize NOT SO important text in a PDF file

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I want to use Spacy to detect important information in a pdf file and redact/sanitize the other NOT SO important text. But Spacy models expect text data as input as  shown below,

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp(u'This is the test input.')
```

How should I use Spacy to perform NLP operations using the PDF file as input and redact/Sanitize some text in the PDF file ?

Comment: Spacy cannot read pdfs natively, you'll have to use another library to read and write the pdf.

Comment: You can check [this](https://support.prodi.gy/t/using-prodigy-with-pdf-documents/322/2) for pdf data processing.

Comment: I have tried extracting text using pypdf2. Now I want to redact some information from it and write it back to the pdf file.